# How to select into temp table and update at once

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, openquery

I have MySql Linked to Sql Server as `STATION_TEST`.
I want to enter the following select results into temporary table and update.
Select Query :

```
SELECT * INTO #MYSqlRFID_Prod FROM OPENQUERY(STATION_TEST,'select * from deslocal.RFID_Prod WHERE valid = ''N''');
```

I can't select twice for update, because table RFID_Prod record is running every time. If i do query like this :

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(STATION_TEST,'SELECT id,valid FROM deslocal.RFID_Prod WHERE valid = ''N''') SET valid = 'Y';
```

I'm afraid the select results will be different from the first select.

Comment: Can you `1.` update valid = 'T' then `2.` place into temp table where valid = `T` and `3.` then update `T` to `Y`

Comment: @Used_By_Already yes it can, but to many process. Is there another way?

Comment: Nothing simple comes to mind, that was my simplest (and most reliable) suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard UPDATE FROM SELECT syntax with linked servers.

```
UPDATE 
   LinkedTable
SET 
   LinkedTable.Field1= 123
FROM
   (
        SELECT *  FROM OPENQUERY(STATION_TEST,'select * from deslocal.RFID_Prod WHERE valid = ''N''')   
   ) AS LinkedTable       
WHERE
    LinkedTable.Field2=456
```

However, if you try to `OUTPUT INSERTED` into a @Temp table, like below:

```
DECLARE @Updated table(Field1 INT,Field2 INT)

WITH X AS(SELECT *  FROM OPENQUERY(STATION_TEST,'select * from deslocal.RFID_Prod WHERE valid = ''N'''))
UPDATE
  T
SET
  T.Field1 = 2212 
OUTPUT 
    INSERTED.Field2,INSERTED.Field2 
    INTO @Updated
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM X )AS T
WHERE 
    T.Field1=123
```

The statement will fail with the following message.

> A remote table cannot be used as a DML target in a statement which includes an OUTPUT clause or a nested DML statement.

Update and select using linked server seems to require two statements.

However.....you might be able to pipe the results of OUTPUT INSERTED INTO a remote table, but then, it would still be a second statement to recall the result set.

Two more options

**Add a critical update correlation key to your target table.**

```
ALTER deslocal ADD(CriticalCorrelationID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
..

DECLARE @CorrelationID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEW_ID()


UPDATE 
    STATION_TEST.YourDatabaseName.dbo.deslocal 
SET 
    Valid='Y',
    CriticalCorrelationID=@CorrelationID 
WHERE
    Valid='N'

SELECT * FROM STATION_TEST.YourDatabaseName.dbo.deslocal 
WHERE CriticalCorrelationID=@CorrelationID
```

**Use Distributed Transaction**

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANS
UPDATE STATION_TEST.YourDatabaseName.dbo.deslocal 
...
SELECT * FROM STATION_TEST.YourDatabaseName.dbo.deslocal WHERE
COMMIT TRANS
```

Comment: @Rosh Bush so how i got the temp table?

Comment: You can't. It is not supported. I have not tried but the OUTPUT INSERTED "might" be routable to your linked server, however, that still would fall short of your goal.

Comment: I added two options that "might" work as an alternative.